# Preprocessor macros substitution

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define LED1_ON() { /* twiddle port bit */ }
#define LED2_ON() { /* twiddle port bit */ }
//  ...
#define LED9_ON() { /* twiddle port bit */ }

#define LED_ON(x) LED##x_ON()
```

I would like to use the above code (or something similar) to have (for example) `LED_ON(1)` call macro `LED1_ON()`, or `LED_ON(2)` call macro `LED2_ON()`.

I believe it is possible to make cpp do this, but clearly I don't have the syntax correct.  Does anyone know the syntax to make this possible?

On the line where I call the `LED_ON(2)`, gcc gives the error message:

```
undefined reference to `LEDx_ON'
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do this. The preprocessor only does one single pass. Maybe you could do something wild with synthesizing include filenames, but I'm not sure it'd be worth it.

Comment: I removed the "cpp" from your title. Many people (unfortunately) use that term to refer to C++, so it could be confusing.

Comment: I don't think there's much point in doing this. There may be a way to make it work, but even if so you'll still only be able to write `LED_ON(3)` rather than `LED3_ON()`; nothing other than a literal `3` would work. On the other hand, an inline function (or even a non-inline function) could easily use a `switch` statement that invokes the proper lower-level macro.

Comment: You'd do much better to reverse the operations.  Write a general `LED_ON(n)` and redefine `#define LED1_ON() LED_ON(1)`, etc.

Comment: What's the difference between the macro bodies? Without seeing that part, and assuming they're treated similarly, the obvious suggestion would be to just define a list of port constants, not to define whole separate macros for each one.

Comment: as to Keith Thompson's comment 2 above, sadly he is right. After getting it to work the way I wanted via Chris Dodd's comment below, I tried to call it like: LED_ON(val), but because of the straight text substitution, it didn't work. Back to an inline function method. Thanks for the effort guys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to define `LED_ON` as

```
#define LED_ON(x)  LED##x##_ON()
```

you want to take the argument `x` and paste on an `LED` prefix and a `_ON` suffix.

Comment: Worked great, exactly what I wanted.  A question though, why is the second pair of ##'s required?

Comment: You need two `##` because you're pasting twice -- adding a prefix and a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the preprocessor mechanism shouldn't be overused. If some more serious logic starts to appear in the macros, maybe it's time to switch to inline functions? They are more readable, just as fast, more powerful and you have some help from the compiler in case of parameter types aso..

If you insist on `#define LED_ON(x)` macro and subsequent LEDs are controlled by subsequent bits of one port, you can try something like this:

```
#define LED_ON(x)   SetBit(port, 1<<x);
```

Comment: I generally agree, but in my case, different ports are used, and the LED numbers otherwise don't correspond to the pin numbers.  (Were I designing the hardware, I would have done it similar to what you assume)

Comment: `#define LED_ON(x)   do{SetBit(port, 1<<(x))}while(0)` would be a better way to write it. Including the semicolon in the macro is asking for trouble and confusion. The `do ... while` construction guarantees that the macro substitution can only be seen as a single entire statement, and cannot be used in an expression. Parenthesis around the formal parameter `x` are strongly recommended to avoid precedence surprises in the evaluation of `1<<x`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
#define LED_ON(num) \
    void LED_ON##num() \
    {\
        printf("set the bit for %d\n", num); \
    }\

LED_ON(1) 
LED_ON(2)

int main() {
    LED_ON1();
    LED_ON2();
}
```

LED_ON(1) and LED_ON(2) will be expanded to full function with name LED_ON1() and LED_ON2() And call functions as LED_ON1() LED_ON2()

Comment: this code is completely wrong. Why are there LED_ON(1) and LED_ON(2) alone on 2 lines?

Comment: LED_ON(1) and LED_ON(2) is outside main(). LED_ON(1) will be macro expanded to full LED_ON1 function. there are many ways you can solve problem, it mainly depends upon your requirement. This code is not wrong. If possible please try to run it on your choice of editor. Please reply if you need more explanation.